# Python Spam filter function column name in function

Tags: python, pandas, function, filter, spam

Hello together i try to build a spam filter now i can't get any further.

I would like to create a function which shows me the probability of a certain word being spam or not.

[table from my data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4aP8.png)

This is my function:

```
def P_E_S(word):
if word in train_set.columns:
    tot_word = train_set.word.sum()
    tot_word_spam = train_set.word[(train_set.type == 'spam')].sum()

    P_word_spam = tot_word_spam / tot_word 
    return P_word_spam
else:
    return 1
```

the problem is that I can't access the column names that way with **word** in line 3 and 4.

If I do the function like this:

```
def P_E_S(word):
if word in train_set.columns:
    tot_word = train_set.make.sum()
    tot_word_spam = train_set.make[(train_set.type == 'spam')].sum()

    P_word_spam = tot_word_spam / tot_word 
    return P_word_spam
else:
    return 1
```

It works perfectly but i need to change the word **make** in line 3 and 4.

Can anyone helps? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Note: `train_set.word` implies that there exists a column named `word` in the `train_set` but in fact it doesn't contain any column named `word`.

*Replace:*

```
train_set.word
```

*With:*

```
train_set[word]
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you explicitly format this as a string, instead of writing `train_set[word]`?

Comment: @IvoMerchiers Nope just casually.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the [] to access it like below:

```
tot_word = train_set[word].sum()
```